# What is the right thing to do with these questions which look copy and pasted?

Tags: discussion, support, flags, duplicate-questions, specific-question

I noticed these two questions in the WPF tag

[How can i close tiny popup or how to style the tiny popup while dragging the control in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30546167/how-can-i-close-tiny-popup-or-how-to-style-the-tiny-popup-while-dragging-the-con)

[How to close the drag and move popup in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30544885/how-to-close-the-drag-and-move-popup-in-wpf)

They're asked by two different users and the titles are slightly different but the question is a direct copy and paste. Is there a way to flag both or something so a mod could check to make sure they aren't spam or a bot or something? Or is there something else I should do?

Comment: Good spot. Mention that there is an "interesting" upvote on the most recent question, as in "why would anyone upvote that". May not be significant, of course, but still...

Comment: They're both downvoted now by the time I flagged it.

Comment: Duplicated question is gone.

Comment: @Bill: Yes, user self-destructed or was killed by mods. Maybe we'll get to hear about it.

Comment: I wouldn't think it's a bot, it seems more likely that the user, after getting a score of -13 and a closed question, figured it was better to start fresh. That's not the way it's supposed to happen on SO, but it's a reasonable thought.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. Use a moderator-intervention-flag on one of them, giving the details:

> This question (aside from title and minimal formatting) is a straight copy-paste of (insert link here) by another user. Please dupe-close (neither is answered yet) and investigate.

If one of them was answered in the SO sense, you should flag for dupe-closure and only ask for further investigation.

If they were from the same user, you should just flag the worse one for closure and downvote it.

Comment: Should I flag them both this way or only the newest one?

Comment: As it is only one thing you want to have them handle, and one flag gives the mods everything relevant, no need to use two.